# (Internet Explorer | Skype) encountered a validation error

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, skype, validation

I just reinstalled Windows 7 with the debugged Service Pack update but every time I run Skype or close Internet Explorer I get this validation error that can be seen here:

[image]

Does anyone know what can be causing this?

The install is legit and I have validated Windows.

When I click "Ignore once", both programs crash; If I click "Ignore always" the error goes but comes back as soon as I run skype again; if I click "Do not ignore" the message just pops back up again.

**EDIT** I downloaded the Windows ISO again and compared the md5 hash with the ISO I installed from, and they are the same. So it's not a corrupted ISO that I installed from as some sites seem to suggest.

**EDIT 2** After some more searching it seems that I am not the only one with this problem as indicated by [this question on Microsoft Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/81cae107-718a-4333-b72e-238ec5924c18) so it seems to be an issue with the ISO from MSDN (my installer is from MSDNAA).

Until this get resolved I'd be very grateful for any suggestions as to how I might fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the guys at MSDNAA got back to me as stated that the issue was with the debugged service pack update.

Basically the option was in a drop-down list but was supposed to be hidden. They made some changes to the site which made the option visible again.

So, if you are downloading Windows 7 from MSDNAA **do not download the debugged service pack**.

Reinstalling the standard version of Win7 made everything work again.